# openerp create a user group which can only view customers

Tags: openerp-7

how can i create a group so that a user can only view customers, no option for edit or create?
I have made a group and given it only read access and assigned it to user but still user is able to create/ modify records.

Kindly guide how to proceed?

Answer (score 0):

Check what other groups that user have. There must be one group with higher privilege would be assigned to the user. because that you are not able to see the effect of your newly created group.